# Bootstrap component fit to the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using bootsrap 3.3.7 and i was trying to make the bootstrap fit to the screen, but i failed. i have search on internet and try but not working.

this is the picture
[image]

i only success to make the navbar fit to the screen, but not the carousel and others.

this is my code

```
    <?php get_header();?>

<br>

        <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>This is Title 1</h3>
                    <p>Some Description</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>This is Title 2</h3>
                    <p>Some Description</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>This is Title 3</h3>
                    <p>Some Description</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <p>Some Description XD</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>


    <br>
    <br>


    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7" >
      <h2 class="featurette-heading"> First featurette heading.<span class="text-muted"> It'll blow your mind. </span> </h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quam sapien, malesuada at massa quis, volutpat consequat velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce tempor justo ante, eget mattis dolor bibendum id. Vivamus sollicitudin auctor ex, non porta tortor efficitur in. Ut eu neque libero. Fusce leo dolor, finibus ut massa a, porta tincidunt justo. Ut elementum scelerisque ligula, congue rhoncus tellus finibus in. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-top: 28px;"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg" alt="404 Not Found" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: auto; height: auto" ></div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-5"  style="padding-top: 28px;"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg" alt="404 Not Found" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: auto; height: auto" ></div>
      <div class="col-md-7"><h2 class="featurette-heading"> Second featurette heading.<span class="text-muted"> It'll blow your mind. </span> </h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quam sapien, malesuada at massa quis, volutpat consequat velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce tempor justo ante, eget mattis dolor bibendum id. Vivamus sollicitudin auctor ex, non porta tortor efficitur in. Ut eu neque libero. Fusce leo dolor, finibus ut massa a, porta tincidunt justo. Ut elementum scelerisque ligula, congue rhoncus tellus finibus in. </p></div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7" >
      <h2 class="featurette-heading"> Third featurette heading.<span class="text-muted"> It'll blow your mind. </span> </h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quam sapien, malesuada at massa quis, volutpat consequat velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce tempor justo ante, eget mattis dolor bibendum id. Vivamus sollicitudin auctor ex, non porta tortor efficitur in. Ut eu neque libero. Fusce leo dolor, finibus ut massa a, porta tincidunt justo. Ut elementum scelerisque ligula, congue rhoncus tellus finibus in. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-top: 28px;"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg" alt="404 Not Found" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: auto; height: auto" ></div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-12"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg" alt="404 Not Found" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: auto; height: auto" ></div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="threeColumn">
        <div class="row" align="center">


          <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg" alt="404 Not Found">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quam sapien, malesuada at massa quis, volutpat consequat velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce tempor justo ante, eget mattis dolor bibendum id. Vivamus sollicitudin auctor ex, non porta tortor efficitur in. Ut eu neque libero. Fusce leo dolor, finibus ut massa a, porta tincidunt justo. Ut elementum scelerisque ligula, congue rhoncus tellus finibus in. </p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg" alt="404 Not Found">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quam sapien, malesuada at massa quis, volutpat consequat velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce tempor justo ante, eget mattis dolor bibendum id. Vivamus sollicitudin auctor ex, non porta tortor efficitur in. Ut eu neque libero. Fusce leo dolor, finibus ut massa a, porta tincidunt justo. Ut elementum scelerisque ligula, congue rhoncus tellus finibus in. </p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>


          <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/404.jpg" alt="404 Not Found">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quam sapien, malesuada at massa quis, volutpat consequat velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce tempor justo ante, eget mattis dolor bibendum id. Vivamus sollicitudin auctor ex, non porta tortor efficitur in. Ut eu neque libero. Fusce leo dolor, finibus ut massa a, porta tincidunt justo. Ut elementum scelerisque ligula, congue rhoncus tellus finibus in. </p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          </div>

    </div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

and this is my css

```html
div.page-content img:first-child {
 max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
div.page-content .item {
    width: 120px;
    min-height: 120px;
    max-height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
}
div.footer-table table {
 
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    padding-top:14px !important; 
    padding-bottom:0 !important;
    height: 48px;
 display : block;
}
.navbar {min-height:48px !important;}

/*
 =================================
 Carrousel CSS
 =================================
*/

.carousel {background: #000;}
.carousel .item {height: auto; overflow: hidden; }
.carousel .item img {width: 100%; height: auto;}
.product .img-responsive {margin: 0 auto;}
.carousel-caption a {color: #fff;}

/*
 =================================
 Navbar CSS
 =================================
*/


.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #1695d4;
  border-color: #1380b6;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 0%, left 100%, from(#33adea), to(#1695d4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #33adea, 0%, #1695d4, 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #33adea 0%, #1695d4 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33adea 0%, #1695d4 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff33adea', endColorstr='#ff1695d4', GradientType=0);
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #046ba6;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #046ba6;
  background-color: #1380b6;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 0%, left 100%, from(#1380b6), to(#18a0e4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1380b6, 0%, #18a0e4, 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1380b6 0%, #18a0e4 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1380b6 0%, #18a0e4 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff1380b6', endColorstr='#ff18a0e4', GradientType=0);
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #dddddd;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-custom .navbar-form {
  border-color: #137eb4;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #046ba6;
  border-bottom-color: #046ba6;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #1380b6;
  color: #046ba6;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #046ba6;
  border-bottom-color: #046ba6;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}
@media (max-width: 767) {
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #046ba6;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #046ba6;
    background-color: #1380b6;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #046ba6;
}

/*
 =================================
 No padding CSS
 =================================
*/

.row.no-pad {
  margin-right:0;
  margin-left:0;
}
.row.no-pad > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

so i want to make template fit to the screen(eg the carousel and other), how to do that? (i know this question duplicated in stackoverflow, i have try the code in another question but not work :'( (i have search and try for 3 hours)

Comment: add your compiled HTML

Comment: show what is get_header() rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `container` Class

replace this class `container-fluid`

Comment: i have try this one, but not working :'( . i wrap all my code in the top with <div class=container-fluid"> </div> and not working. still same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to override the css with `!important` :

```
.row {
  margin:10px 0 10px 0 !important;
}
```

EDIT : Be sure that you call your stylesheet after the bootstrap style in your  `get_header()`

Answer (score 0):

There are some hacks you can do! some of them are -

use jQuery:

```
 var body_width = $('body').width();
$('.row').css('width', (body_width));
$('.row').css('margin-left', ('-'+(body_width/2)+'px'));
```

replace .row class with your divs class wanted to be 100% width.

use container-fluid:

wrapping up your components in .container-fluid will work as charm, if it does not try to put parts of html in different .container-fluid divs.

your working example : https://jsfiddle.net/ishusupah/cxs3xyop/1/